# Windows process management using Python

Tags: python, windows, process

I need a script that check if a particular process is running and return something if not found. I know that this can be done using subprocess, but is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Take a look at: [getting process information on windows](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/305279/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Windows, you can use WMI:

```
import win32com.client

def find_process(name):
    objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
    objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(".", "root\cimv2")
    colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery(
         "Select * from Win32_Process where Caption = '{0}'".format(name))
    return len(colItems)

print find_process("SciTE.exe")
```

Comment: The wmi module will make this even easier. http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html It is a lightweight wrapper around win32com

Comment: Why bother to retrieve the whole process list, when the `Select` statement will let you pre-filter on the `Caption`?  Like this: `"Select * from Win32_Process where Caption = 'SciTE.exe'"`

Comment: have you checked this to work on xp? I don't have a xp machine with me to check right now.

Answer (score 1):

For similar purposes I have used [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) library. Some hints:

- list processes with `psutil.pids()` ([reference](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.pids))
- inspect process information with `process = psutil.Process(pid)` ([reference](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#process-class))
- do `process.kill` or `process.terminate()`

[Installation](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/INSTALL.rst) on windows - `pip` will do installation from the source (which means compiling), so you probably want to download binary installation from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/#downloads.