# How to determine which executable from a list is running

Tags: python, windows, process

I have a path where I have many executables (around 800). I need to know if some of those executables are running. This is because I need to run a build and if the executables are running I cannot recreate them (access error when linker is invoked).

What I do currently is to run `taskkill` (I am on Windows platform) on all those executables. This takes time and I'd like to know if there's a faster/better way.

The build scripts are written in python but other solutions are welcome if we can easily integrate them.

Iulian

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python, List running processes 64Bit Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632234/python-list-running-processes-64bit-windows) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084111/windows-process-management-using-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For similar purposes I have used [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) library. Some hints:

- list processes with `psutil.pids()` ([reference](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.pids))
- inspect process information with `process = psutil.Process(pid)` ([reference](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#process-class))
- do `process.kill` or `process.terminate()`

[Installation](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/INSTALL.rst) on windows - `pip` will do installation from the source (which means compiling), so you probably want to download binary installation from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/#downloads.